# StaticLayout maxLineHeight should not be -1. maxLines:1 lineCount:1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Forms that will be deployed to Android devices. While troubleshooting some of the warnings I am receiving, I see the following warning in the console:

`[StaticLayout] maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1`

This warning is only showing up when I implement `LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"` on a label that extends past the one line. It will repeat the error in the console for every label that needs to be truncated. There is no public property `maxLineHeight` that I can find to manipulate.

At this point I believe it is a bug in Xamarin and Android, and am pretty sure I can ignore this line, but if anyone had an answer as to  **why I am receiving this message and how to correct it**, I would really appreciate it.

The following two files are the relevant code pieces to replicate this issue. Notice, I tried all methods of `LineBreakMode` and only the `TailTruncation` is showing the warning.

*MainPage.xaml.cs*:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> LabelTexts { get; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            LabelTexts = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            BindingContext = this;

            InitializeComponent();

            GenerateLabels();

        }

        private async void GenerateLabels()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(6000).Wait();

                LabelTexts.Add("A short text");
                LabelTexts.Add("A medium text (at least a little longer)");
                LabelTexts.Add("A text so long that it'll get clipped and then we see a warning when using tail truncation only");
            });

        }
    }
```

*MainPage.xaml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:testtruncationbinding="clr-namespace:TestTruncationBinding"
             x:Class="TestTruncationBinding.MainPage"
             x:DataType="testtruncationbinding:MainPage">

    <CollectionView x:Name="CollectionView"  ItemsSource="{Binding LabelTexts}" BackgroundColor="DeepPink">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="1"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Text="{Binding .}" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,3,0" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>  <!-- WARNING IF THIS IS THE LineBreakMode active-->
                <!-- <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Text="{Binding .}" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,3,0" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/> -->
                <!-- <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Text="{Binding .}" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,3,0" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="MiddleTruncation"/> -->
                <!-- <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Text="{Binding .}" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,3,0" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"/> -->
                <!-- <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Text="{Binding .}" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,3,0" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="HeadTruncation"/> -->
                <!-- <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Text="{Binding .}" Margin="0" Padding="3,0,3,0" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/> -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

And my *App.Xaml.cs*:

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it actually causing a problem?  It not, then ignore it.

Comment: My concern was that it would slow performance if every time it tries to draw it also has to take note of these warnings. It logs the warning for each instance, so when number of labels being rendered is large, it may start to slow things. If it is just a message that is printed out during DEBUG builds then that's one thing, but if it is ALWAYS checking and reporting back that the `maxLineHeight` is messed up then that would be problematic and could cause performance impacts.

Comment: Even in Debug builds, I've never observed any detectable performance impact. From warnings, or any of the other countless messages that go to console. **If in doubt, run without Debugger attached:** an attached debugger is by far the biggest factor that makes Debug builds run slower than Release builds, because JIT optimization is suppressed, so that breakpoints and exceptions know which byte code corresponds to each line of source code. When no debugger, Debug runs nearly as fast as Release build.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I'm not running into performance issues besides when scrolling this with a debugger attached. For now I'll chalk it up as something to ignore. Thanks everyone!